# set a javascript Null value if a python value is None in Jinja Expression

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2

I want to set a default value in javascript in case the {{ }} jinja expression returns nothing. This way the javascript does not throw an error.

Is there some way to make a default value like this in the HTML file:

```
<script>
  var info= {{ python_info | safe }}?self:null;
</script>
```

If python_info is "" then I want the javascript to be null or some other default value.

I know you can could do an || or solution but this messes up the linting even worse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below should work

```
<script>
  var info = {{ python_info if python_info else 'null' }};
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves the default issue using python, but it will still throw an issue for the javascript linter...

Comment: would it not be better to do the python code like this python_info or 'null'

Comment: @Zaffer what does the js linter complain about? The code is not js - it is a jinja2 that will be translated to js. So running a js linter on a jinja template does not make sense.

Comment: good point, I guess I looking for a hack to get around the use of JINJA with JS linter. If you can help me think a simple hack like surrounding in "" if it was a string. but this also causes issues. I will edit my question to remove the second part, as one issue per question is probably better.

Comment: I have an unexpected problem with this. I am passing a json string into this python_info, but when I go: {{ python_info  | safe }} it reads fine in JavaScript. but when it is {{ python_info if python_info else 'null' }} then it escapes the json and makes the json look like this: {&#34;users&#34;: [{&#34;id&#34;: 743, &#34;....